# the method can only set one of public / protected / private

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I'm implementing an interface:

```
public interface Consultant {
    // some documentation here explaining it should throw 3 types of exceptions
    CellLocation suggest(GameBoard gameBoard);
}
```

It uses another interface:

```
public interface GameBoard {
    CellState getCellState(CellLocation cellLocation);
}
```

I wrote a lot of methods, but just started implementing the all-important suggest method. It looks like this so far:

```
public class YourConsultant implements Consultant {
    @Override
    public CellLocation suggest(GameBoard gameBoard) {
        char[][] arrayBoardGlobal;
        Player currentPlayerGlobal;
        GameState gameStateGlobal;
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I get the error

> The method suggest in type YourConsultant can only set one of public / protected / private

Of course I cannot change it from public to anything else because of the interface.

What could be the cause? I haven't found the answer here or the net, probably because it brings up basic info about access modifiers. I'm using Eclipse Neon.

Comment: I strongly suspect there's something wrong in the surrounding context. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The `@Override` annotation is wrong because with interfaces you do not override things. I suspect that you have a `class` somewhere which has a `suggest(GameBoard gb)` which defaults to protected but we really need to see more code to answer this question.

Comment: found this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=130117. Which jdk are you using?

Comment: It's quite possible that the `@Override` annotation is wrong. I got the code this way.

I hope it's not the bug as I don't know how to do a workaround :)

Okay, I'll make an example, but it will take some time.

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.8.0_91

Comment: @mroman, it's actually supported (and encouraged) to annotate interface method implementations with `@Override` as of JDK 1.6 and above. But I do agree that the cause is likely in the surrounding code of `YourConsultant`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Okay, I found the error... I left a lonely "private" tag hanging in the air a few lines before YourConsultant :D. Your comments were helpful, especially the one asking for a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example